# Error in Selenium Testcase playback

Tags: selenium, selenium-rc

I always get this error whenever I try to playback a testcase in Selenium

```
   [error] Permission denied for <http://www.facebook.com> to get property Location.href
```

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are bumping into javascript's same-domain security policy.

See here: http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=117050.

Without more information about your test case, it's hard to be specific, but the basic problem might be

> JavaScript has a same domain policy for security reasons. That means
>   it can not touch other domains.

In the example in the linked resource, the user was able to replace

```
top.document.location.href = searchLocation;
```

with

```
window.open(searchLocation, "_top");
```

to solve the problem.